# iPhone device with a separator nsstring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios-simulator

I'm using a nsstring like separator, but when I show by console with simulator shows me well but when I do it with my iphone 4S shows me other thing.
I try to parse to utf8, ascii and i can´t solve it.
Can somebody tell me why its happening this??

```
#define SEPARATOR @"ääëëñS0ñççää"
```

- Iphone Simulator:
  NSLog(@"%@",SEPARATOR); -->text in terminal: ääëëñS0ñççää`
- my Iphone 4S:

  NSLog(@"%@",SEPARATOR); -->text in terminal: √§√§√´√´√±S0√±√ß√ß√§√§`

  ```
  const char *utf8String = [SEPARADOR UTF8String];

  NSString *stringFromUTFString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:utf8String];

  NSLog(@"%@",stringFromUTFString);
  ```

Now, i did it this, and when i use the simulator show me the SEPARATOR correctly, however  when i use my device he pass me the text to NSISOLatin1StringEncoding.

Comment: What about `NSLog(@"%@", SEPARATOR);`?

Comment: yes, and show me this with simulator: ääëëñS0ñççää`and this with my device: √§√§√´√´√±S0√±√ß√ß√§√§

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode's simulator uses the system fonts(Mac machine) to render the text, but the iPhone uses only the fonts embedded in it, which means all fonts available in the simulator may not be available on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSString *SEPARATOR = @"ääëëñS0ñççää";
NSLog(@"%s",[SEPARATOR UTF8String]);
```

That said, you should have the Font running both on the Mac running the simulator and the device itself, Since you are dealing with specific language - both Mac and iOS device should have this language installed.

It seems that you should go into setting on your device and enable whatever language you are dealing with...

Comment: I have tried and return this: ‚àö¬ß‚àö¬ß‚àö¬¥‚àö¬¥‚àö¬±S0‚àö¬±‚àö√ü‚àö√ü‚àö¬ß‚àö¬ß

Comment: but is not a specific language is iso latin 1.